# Using environment variables in a Java File Path

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I am writing a Java program to convert an XLS file to a CSV file for some Python parsers to act on them.

Everyday on my desktop (I'm using Ubuntu btw) I have a folder called "DFiles" inside which there is another folder called "20140705" (this folder is dynamicalle generated, tomorrow some other program deletes this folder and makes a new folder called 20140706 in its place). Inside this folder there is an xls file whose name is always "data.xls". I already have the code to convert it to CSV.

So here's my problem. Tomorrow my code my run on someone else's desktop(which is also Ubuntu). So when giving the path

```
input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/local/TNA/srini/Desktop/DFiles/20140705/data.xls"+));
```

This unfortunately will work only today and only on my computer.

Ideally, I would like to do some thing like set the path to "$HOME/Desktop/Dfiles/2*/data.xls" as the file path. So how can I use bash env variables and wild cards in a file path in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of an environment variable using `System.getenv(...)`:

```
String homeDir = System.getenv("HOME");
String directory = homeDir + "/Desktop/DFiles/...";
```

Wildcards: That will not work. You can use `listFiles()` to list the files and directories inside a certain directory.

```
File dir = new File(homeDir + "/Desktop/DFiles";
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Found subdirectory: " + f.getName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Found file: " + f.getName());
    }
}
```

You can write some code that recursively goes into the subdirectories and picks up any file of which the name ends with '.xls'.

Comment: All right, I'll try that. Can you also tell me how to use the wildcard character(*) in a file path?